# Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark')

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Using the latest version on android (23) with *com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1* and *com.android.support:design:23.0.1*

I'm getting the following error

> Error:(20, 118) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'drawable' with value
>   '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').

[image]

When clicking on the error I see that I can get to the drawable
[image]

On similar cases in stackoverflow I see a mismatch between the versions number like in the [following case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943180/no-resource-found-errors-for-supportappcompat-v722-0-0-on-android-studio)

My Gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "a.b.c.d.defg"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the issue and it had nothing to do with the description above.

Thanks to @fvasquezc23 suggestion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359572/android-studio-execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-if-project) I looked and found that my path in was longer than 255 characters.

I moved the project location and shortened the directories names.

It is most likely that the paths that gave me the error were just longer than the path limit.

Unfortunately, I didn't supply the path in my question so it was hard to provide a good advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing. I had a similar problem with jenkins building, some targets were working and others not, the problem was their name making the path exceed 255 chars.

Comment: Yes, making the general folder path short and not including any special characters (i.e. @ character) in the folder name solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

great answer by Ika. I faced the exact same issue and problem was solved by making the overall patch short including the project name.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue in two ways:

1.
Move the Project folder location to a shorter directory name.

2.
Window support maximum file path of 260 character. 
To allow more than 260 character you need to do Registry Edit in windows

Goto **RegEdit** 
-> Right-click on **FileSystem** 
-> Choose New > DWORD (32-bit) Value  
-> Name the new value LongPathsEnabled   
-> Change the value from 0 to 1 in the “Value data” box 
-> Press OK  
-> Restart PC