# Build failed in react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources

Tags: windows, react-native

Im new in react-native and I follow the installation f8app in [makeitopen.com](http://makeitopen.com).
everything is smooth before I tried to do `react-native run-android`. When I run that command, comes the error that I don't know. Here is the error log.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResourc
es'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' fin
ished with non-zero exit value 1
```

FYI
I'm using Android SDK Build tools 23.0.2.

I hope you guys can help me with this, since I'm very interested in react-native.

Thank you

EDIT at (17-may-2016)

this is the full error log

```
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml:5:27-80 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml:8:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml:11:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml:5:27-81 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml:8:27-80 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml:11:27-80 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml:13:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml:7:27-80 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml:10:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml:13:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml:5:27-81 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml:8:27-80 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml:11:27-80 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml:13:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light.xml:5:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled').
D:\My Files\programming\react-native\f8app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\RNPushNotificationAndroid\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.3.0\res\drawable\common_plus_signin_btn_text_light.xml:5:27-79 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_disabled').

:react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 39.493 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Comment: Hey.. Can you share the entire error log. Unable to find any reason from the existing message you shared.

Comment: I have added the full error log as you said @Jickson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows OS when the filename is too big you get this error message while building the app.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33337655/2125612) for more info.

Comment: finally did it by adding 

dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
after defaultConfig

and move the project folder to directory D:/f8app

thank u @Jickson