# Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'

Tags: android, react-native

when i run the demo https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript/tree/master/react-native-sample/SendBirdReactNativeSample in Ubuntu16.04, it fail

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'.
> at index 4
```

I have seach [Build failed in react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192923/build-failed-in-react-native-push-notificationprocessreleaseresources) and https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues, but it seems that there are not any answers helping me.

Please help me.

thx in advance.

Comment: Had the same problem on windows and this worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943180/no-resource-found-errors-for-supportappcompat-v722-0-0-on-android-studio/33337655#33337655